# Why are rationals algebraic numbers if they are not roots of equations of higher order than $1$?

Tags: group-theory, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, field-theory, rational-numbers

From reading about [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number), the definition is that an algebraic number is a number that is a root of a non-zero polynomial in one variable with integer (or, equivalently, rational) coefficients.
*All* rational numbers are considered algebraic because any rational number is the root of a non-zero polynomial, namely $ax + b$

If I understand correctly though, $ax + b$ is a special case of the binomial equation $ax^n + b = 0$ and for $n = 1$ we have the polynomial $ax + b$ which we consider that has roots in the rational domain.
But I don't understand why we consider that the rational numbers are algebraic numbers if they are not solutions to $ax^n + b$ as well. E.g. they are not for $x^2 - 2 = 0$
Is it not required that all equations of higher degree be reducible to equations of the type $ax + b$ in order to consider the rationals as algebraic numbers?

Comment: You've assigned the name $n$ to the number $1$, and then said "but now let $n$ range over all the naturals, and it's all gone wrong". Yes, of course it all goes wrong if you let $1$ range over all the naturals!

Comment: @PatrickStevens: I am trying to understand if the requirement is that for a number set to be considered algebraic it must be the solution to all algebraic equations or not. Alternatively are all algebraic equations reducible to $ax +b$ hence making rationals algebraic?

Comment: No, there is no number which is a solution to all algebraic equations. I challenge you to find a simultaneous solution to $x=0$ and $x+1=0$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: So the rationals are algebraic numbers because they are all solutions to one type and only one type of polynomial equation? And it is irrelevant if they are not for the rest? Have I got it right?

Comment: Yes, basically correct. What matters is that *any given rational* is a root of *some* (integer-coefficient) polynomial.

Comment: It's very simple: a number is algebraic if it is the root of _at least one_ non-zero polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: @TonyK: I was under the understanding that general quadratic equations are expressible by means of rational numbers and quadratic surds. And the same for equations up to the $4$th degree. (i.e. are capable of a formal solution by means of radicals with exponent at most $4$). But the elementary radical $\root n \of x$ or something composite such as $a + \root 2 \of b$ do not seem to be considered algebraic. What is the difference with rational numbers then?

Comment: You are all over the place! What do you mean by a 'quadratic equation' being 'expressible'? Do you mean a 'polynomial' being 'solvable' (which is an entirely different topic)? You are mixing up expressions, polynomials, and numbers as if they were all the same thing!

Comment: @TonyK: If we have $x^2+2x+1$ this is expressed as $(x + 1)(x+1)$ so it is of type $ax + b$ which is solved by rationals. I read that up to the $4$ degree (proved by Ferrari) similar reduction is possible using radicals, so I was trying to understand why aren't radicals also considered as algebraic if they can be the basis of solutions to algebraic equations. (Galois proved that it is impossible for higher than degree $4$)

Comment: @Jim "*...do not seem to be considered algebraic*" $\;-\;$ You must have misunderstood something. If $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ then $\sqrt[n]{b}$ and $a+\sqrt[n]{b}$ are algebraic numbers for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

The roots of $x^2-2$ are algebraic, but also the roots of $x^7-23x^4+37x-1$ (a polynomial I wrote with random coefficients).

There's nothing in the definition of algebraic number that requires to consider only polynomials of the form $ax^n+b$. The roots of such a polynomial *are* algebraic numbers, but the set of algebraic numbers is larger.

Of course general polynomials with integer coefficients are *not* reducible to factors of the form $ax+b$, otherwise every algebraic number would be rational.

We *do* want that rational numbers are algebraic, don't we? If you're worried about the degree, then consider that the rational number $r$ is a root of $(x-r)^n$, which has the degree you want and rational coefficients.

And if you want a polynomial of the form $ax^n+b$ with $n>1$, this can be accommodated as well. Say you have $r=p/q$, with $p$ and $q$ integers. Then $r$ is a root of $q^nx^n-p^n$, for every $n$.

Comment: I was under the understanding that general quadratic equations are expressible by means of rational numbers and quadratic surds. And the same for equations up to the $4$th degree. (i.e. are capable of a formal solution by means of radicals with exponent at most $4$). But the elementary radical $\root n \of x$ or something composite such as $a + \root 2 \of b$ do not seem to be considered algebraic. What is the difference with rational numbers then?

Comment: @jim Sorry, you’re on the wrong track. For instance you may need cube roots to represent roots of quartic polynomials.Also, if $a,b$ are rational, $a+\sqrt[n]{b}$ definitely is algebraic.